# How do I add a block to a page?

Tags: blocks

I have a page in which I want to add a block.  The block is located in `design/frontend/default/<theme>/template/<folder>/test.phtml` and at the moment contains nothing more than a simple `<?php echo "Test"; ?>` statement.

In my page Content in the Magento admin I have the following:

```
{{block type=”core/template” template=”<folder>/test.phtml”}}
```

But the block doesn't seem to be getting loaded.  Even when I put a `die("test")` in the block file I don't see the `test` string getting printed anywhere.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple...

Answer (score 1):

It was the smartquotes!  *facepalm*

Changing

```
{{block type=”core/template” template=”<folder>/test.phtml”}}
```

to

```
{{block type="core/template" template="<folder>/test.phtml"}}
```

did the trick